# Multiple row setup not working in IE

Tags: css, html

I have an issue with my CSS.
I have a very simple setup. 2 divs that each contain 3 buttons. I would EXPECT them to each take up 1 row, so it's 2 rows with 3 buttons in each.

This is also what Chrome does, but IE9 puts them all in one row, and even screws with the position of one of the buttons.

I have the following HTML:

```
<div id="HelpCodesControl">
    <div class="ButtonRow">
        <button id="HelpCode_None" title="None" />
        <button id="HelpCode_Operator" title="Operator" />
        <button id="HelpCode_Maintenance" title="Maintenance" />
    </div>

    <div class="ButtonRow">
        <button id="HelpCode_Quality" title="Quality" />
        <button id="HelpCode_Warehouse" title="Warehouse" />
        <button id="HelpCode_Setup" title="Setup" />
    </div>
</div>
```

And my CSS:

```
#HelpCodesControl {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: cadetblue;
}
.ButtonRow {
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
.ButtonRow button {
    height: 48px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

I have my example here, where it works as I would think in Chrome but not in IE9: http://jsfiddle.net/M96r3/

So what am I doing wrong? Why does IE9 not show my buttons in two rows, like Chrome?

Comment: @MrLister You are correct! I was not aware that I couldn't close buttons like that. If you post as answer I'll accept.

Comment: OK, I've put it up as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are structural errors in the HTML: the buttons aren't closed properly.

```
<button id="HelpCode_None" title="None" />
```

should be

```
<button id="HelpCode_None" title="None"></button>
```

As it is now, the browsers sees only six start tags and no end tags, which in principle nests the buttons inside each other (although no browser displays them like that; some browsers only show 2 buttons though. Different browsers respond differently to errors).

In XHTML, you could get away with this - it is well-formed XML after all - but it's *STRONGLY* discouraged, as it would cause troubles with browsers that try to display XHTML in HTML mode. Use self-closing tags only for void elements!

Here is an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M96r3/6/) with the HTML corrected, that shows there is no drastic difference in display between IE and other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `display: table-cell;` instead of `display: inline-block;` but my suggestion is that use `display: inline-block;` for `button` not to `.ButtonRow` for your requirement.

Comment: You are right, it should definitely be on the button instead. It still gives me the same result though :(

Comment: but also apply width 100% to .ButtonRow and even apply `display: table'` or `display: table-row`

Comment: I still get 1 row in IE9.

Comment: Yeah, I noted It's a bug of ie.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your Header ? If its work with chrome or other web browser but not IE, try replacing your Header with :

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```